# Avoiding Cross Side Scripting in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, xss

I am currently coding a registration module. Basically, it's a registration module that takes the user info from asp.net site and sends them to the SQL server. I made significant changes but I still have XSS issues when I scan it with `acunetix`. The registration module works just fine but I wanted to avoid XSS. Because it's clearly vulnerable and it did not pass the acunetix scan.
The last code that I came up with is below. It's a button click event.

```
        Dim connQuery As String = "Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim cs As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connQuery)
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim table As String = "[mydatabase].[dbo].[users]"
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO " & table & "(passwd, FName, LName, Organization, TelNo, FaxNo, Title, Email, User_type, GroupID, Activated, request_num, FirstLogin, LastLogin, IsLoggedin, IsOutsideInv, WI, study_type) VALUES (@passwd, @FName, @LName, @Organization, @TelNo, @FaxNo, @Title, @Email, @User_type, @GroupID, @Activated, @request_num, @FirstLogin, @LastLogin, @IsLoggedin, @IsOutsideInv, @WI, @study_type)"

    Try

        da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(query, cs)

        ' da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@passwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@passwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = encode(txtPassword.Text)
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Organization", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtOrg.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FaxNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFax.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@User_type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@GroupID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 0
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Activated", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0 
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@request_num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstLogin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateAndTime.Now
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastLogin", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateAndTime.Now
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsLoggedin", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsOutsideInv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 0
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WI", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtInves.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@study_type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 0 

        cs.Open()
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cs.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Labelmessage.Text = "Error while adding record to the database ==> " & ex.Message.ToString()
    Finally
        cs.Close()
    End Try
```

What would be the ideal way to pass this scan? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with VBA? Should this have been tagged VB.NET? The two are NOT the same!

Comment: You're right. Sorry!

Comment: XSS is where you create the output html, it has nothing to do with the database queries.

Comment: Btw storing plain text passwords is a Really Bad Idea. Please use bcrypt or pbkdf2.

Comment: storing the password as plain text code has been marked as a comment. Please see the next line which password is encrypted.